# PHPStorm, Auto-Completion in querybuilder (Doctrine / Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, plugins, autocomplete, phpstorm, query-builder

I recently installed phpstorm 10.0.3 to work on my symfony2 project.

Then I installed Symfony Plugin 0.11.109, i tried some features, they work well, expect one : [Completion for QueryBuilder](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Doctrine+-+Symfony+Development+using+PhpStorm#WorkingwithDoctrine-SymfonyDevelopmentusingPhpStorm-CompletionforQueryBuilder)

So, I tried to fix my issue :
- I installed PHP Annotation 2.6.2
- I did a doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
- I installed and conf' Database Tools ans SQL v1.0

And autocomplete didn't work.

Any idea ?

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Did you tried to synchronize ? (File->Synchronize)

Comment: Thanks for you answer !
I tried, but nothing new

Comment: Also tried  File->Invalidate caches/restart ?

Comment: It works ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my problem ! I used a protected method to get the Repository Name (as a string) to init the repo.

Now I init the repo directly with the string.

Hope that's will help !

[image]